# Use Proj (Proj4) to convert UTM coordinate to Cartesian coordinate relative to an Earth tangent plane with its origin define as lon/lat?

Tags: coordinate-system, proj, pyproj, proj4js

I may have asked in the wrong place here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61147814. Then I discovered http://gis.stackexchange.com, so I decided to ask again here:

I have a UTM coordinate (zone, hemisphere, northing, easting, height) where height is in meters.

I want to convert this coordinate into a custom format (or vice versa) where I choose an arbitrary plane that is tangent to the Earth. The tangent point of the plane has a longitude/latitude with height of zero (it "touches" Earth at that point).

The X axis of the tangent plane points North, Y points West, and Z points up. I refer to this coordinate system as "North/West/Up" or "NWU".

Once I have the tangent plane, I define all points relative to the plane's origin (tangent point) in NWU coordinates of meter units.

An NWU coordinate basically looks like (lon, lat, X, Y, Z) which can also be referred to as (lon, lat, N, W, U) where (lon, lat) describes the touch point of the tangent plane and the origin from which all NWU points are relative to.

This is what the tangent plane looks like:

[image: tangent plane]

Given a UTM coordinate (zone, hemisphere, easting, northing, height), how can I use PROJ to convert it to/from the NWU coordinates of (lon, lat, N, W, U) where (lon, lat) is predefined? I.e. What would the PROJ strings for this be?

If the (lon, lat) are hard-coded into the strings, that's fine. I can template them depending on which tangent plane I choose.

I don't know if the latitude is geocentric or geodetic. For this case assume the same Lon/Lat as what Google Maps and most other mapping systems use.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per question. You have a number of question marks and additional statements that are further questions, making the question difficult to answer without a significant level of effort (our Answers try to be pages, not chapters, multi-chapter sections, or books).

Comment: @Vince Hello, and thanks! I wrote multiple questions, but I think it is more of re-wording the same overall question: How to make that conversion with Proj? I can try to re-word it to have only a single question.

Comment: This may help with building the custom CRS: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/build_crs.html.

Answer (score 3):

You are defining a topocentric, or local cartesian, system.

From the ["4.1.2 Geocentric/topocentric conversions" section of IOGP Geomatics Guidance Note 7, part 2 (Revision of March 2019)](http://www.epsg.org/Portals/0/373-07-2.pdf):

[image: 1]

---

The process to transform coordinates from a topocentric system to any other one with PROJ is interesting. Since the CRS is not implemented (see https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/issues/500), the transformation implies always a step to geocentric coordinates through an affine transformation.

The rotation matrix to align an *ENU (Easth, North, Up)* system to the geocentric one is:

[image: 2]

Where `lambda_0` is the longitude and `phi_0` is the latitude, of the topocentric point.

But you want to go from a *NWU (North, West, Up)* system. We can compose the transformation, but for the sake of simplicity we will do it in two steps.

First, transform coordinates from a *NWU* to an *ENU* system, applying a 90 degrees clockwise rotation around the *Up* axis, through a [PROJ Affine Transformation](https://proj.org/operations/transformations/affine.html) pipeline, with the [cct application](https://proj.org/apps/cct.html):

```
C:\>cct +proj=pipeline +step +proj=affine +s11=0 +s12=-1 +s21=1 +s22=0
1000 0 0
       0.0000      1000.0000        0.0000           inf
0 1000 0
   -1000.0000         0.0000        0.0000           inf
0 0 1000
       0.0000         0.0000     1000.0000           inf
```

We are entering *NWU* coordinates and the application is returning *ENU* coordinates. The fourth coordinate is time, and we will not work with it.

Next, perform the transformation to geocentric coordinates.

You must compute the rotation matrix with sines and cosines of latitude and longitude. I will assume the topocentric point at *(longitude=0, latitude=0, ellipsoidal height=0)* coordinates.

The translation vecor is created with the geocentric coordinates of the topocentric point. These coordinates can be calculated with the [cart conversion method](https://proj.org/operations/conversions/cart.html):

```
C:\>cct +proj=lonlat +to +proj=cart +ellps=WGS84
0 0 0
 6378137.0000         0.0000        0.0000           inf
```

We are entering *(longitude, latitude, ellipsoidal height)* coordinates and retrieving *(X,Y,Z)* WGS84 geocentric coordinates.

So, to transform from *NWU* to *WGS84 geocentric* coordinates:

```
C:\>cct +proj=pipeline +step +proj=affine +s11=0 +s12=-1 +s21=1 +s22=0 +step +proj=affine +s11=0 +s12=0 +s13=1 +s21=1 +s22=0 +s23=0 +s31=0 +s32=1 +s33=0 +xoff=6378137 +yoff=0 +zoff=0
0 0 0
 6378137.0000         0.0000        0.0000           inf
1000 0 0
 6378137.0000         0.0000     1000.0000           inf
0 1000 0
 6378137.0000     -1000.0000        0.0000           inf
0 0 1000
 6379137.0000         0.0000        0.0000           inf
```

Finally, we can transform from geocentric coordinates to any system supported by PROJ. For instance, we can ask the pipeline to transform from WGS84 geocentric to WGS84 UTM zone 30 North:

```
C:\>projinfo -o PROJ -s EPSG:4978 -t EPSG:32630
Candidate operations found: 1
-------------------------------------
Operation No. 1:

unknown id, Conversion from WGS 84 (geocentric) to WGS 84 (geog2D) + UTM zone 30N, 0 m, World

PROJ string:
+proj=pipeline +step +inv +proj=cart +ellps=WGS84 +step +proj=utm +zone=30 +ellps=WGS84
```

So, all we need to do is include the step at the end of our pipeline:

```
C:\>cct +proj=pipeline +step +proj=affine +s11=0 +s12=-1 +s21=1 +s22=0 +step +proj=affine +s11=0 +s12=0 +s13=1 +s21=1 +s22=0 +s23=0 +s31=0 +s32=1 +s33=0 +xoff=6378137 +yoff=0 +zoff=0 +step +inv +proj=cart +ellps=WGS84 +step +proj=utm +zone=30 +ellps=WGS84
0 0 0
  833978.5569         0.0000        0.0000           inf
1000 0 0
  833978.5528      1000.9811        0.0789           inf
0 1000 0
  832977.5800         0.0000        0.0784           inf
0 0 1000
  833978.5569         0.0000     1000.0000           inf
```

For the inverse transformation, just include the `-I` parameter in the command.

---

Notes:

- The latitude, as you have drawn it, is geocentric. All calculations are defined from geodetic latitude. It is important, because if the body is an ellipsoid of revolution, a plane which is orthogonal to geocentric latitude is not tangent to the ellipsoid surface.
- If you understand what happen with ellipsoidal heights in a local cartesian system compared to an orthographic projection, and you think that the last one is correct for your system, so you are looking for that system instead, and it is implemented in PROJ.

Comment: An orthographic projection essentially fits the definition he is looking for and will handle the conversion from geodetic UTM heights into this new frame. Since his major axes are aligned with global N-S and E-W, this does not have to be represented as a "local" CRS.

All of these details are mathematically complex and using a prepackaged orthographic projection will likely lead to better results; the user likely wants to use ellipsoidal calculations although he drew a sphere, and Proj will give better results than hacking something together along these lines.

Comment: I'll try to be simple: suppose the center at (latitude 0, longitude 0). All (latitude 1, longitude 1) points will be mapped to the same location on an orthographic projection, regardless of their ellipsoidal height. In a local Cartesian system that does not happen.

Comment: @DavenQuinn Tagging you so you can see Gabriel's reply. Any thoughts? Gabriel, I think what you're saying is that height values would be ignored? If that the case, could I just supply the original height values after I do the PROJ conversion? If so, then would Daven's ortho project idea work?

Comment: My solution treats heights separately from the projective transformation: in this solution, the correct method is to supply the original heights after Proj conversion.

Gabriel is correct that my solution ignores the angular effect of the Earth's curvature when transforming vertical values. Depending on your exact goals, this might still be preferable because 1. the Proj-based transformation is much simpler and 2. differences will be small if your UTM coordinates cover a small area. Ultimately, which is correct depends on how you want your heights to be represented in the new frame.

Comment: I will also add that "rolling your own" projection as Gabriel suggests might be appropriate if you have a very specific mathematical/geodetic target in mind, but unless you really know what you are doing, you will likely cause more problems than you solve.

Comment: @trusktr, No, I don't say that. The tangent plane system is not a projection, and it is not "your own projection". This system is just not supported by PROJ. Its conversion method is included in the EPSG database (EPSG:4461) and it is supported by the LocalCartesian class of GeographicLib. You asked how to do it with PROJ and I answer it.

Answer (score 0):

A projection onto a tangent plane is essentially the definition of an "orthographic" projection; basically, this is a planar perspective projection viewed from infinity, so all lines of projection are perpendicular to a tangent plane.

This is a foundational projection type, and the transformation is easily represented as a Proj transform. See [the Proj documentation](https://proj.org/operations/projections/ortho.html) for details. Your Proj4 string will be something like `+proj=ortho +lat_0=[tangent lat] +lon_0=[tangent lon]`.

You will simply need to use Proj4 do the conversion between UTM and this projection. This assumes that you want your projected coordinates X Y Z in a north-up, positive-east order — if not, you will have to rotate them into that frame after projecting.

Comment: I don't think this will work well if your height is significantly above or below the geoid, since the ortho projection is purely 2D, and doesn't take any height info. You can verify this by passing an altitude, and and even if you are significantly far away from the origin of the orthographic projection, the altitude does not change, when it should for true local tangent plane coordinates.