# Transforming to NED coordinate system

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, openstreetmap, geopandas

I’m working with a map that I've downloaded from OSM (EPSG:4326, using geopandas). Ideally, I would like to convert to a locally predefined *NED (North-Ease-Down)/ENU(East-North-Up)* coordinate system using a predefined (lat0,lon0,height0) coordinates. I’ve seen several posts and comments about this subject but still I can’t get it right.

1. https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/pull/2444
2. [Generating custom projection in pyproj](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/330445/generating-custom-projection-in-pyproj)
3. [Use Proj (Proj4) to convert UTM coordinate to Cartesian coordinate relative to an Earth tangent plane with its origin define as lon/lat?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/357910/use-proj-proj4-to-convert-utm-coordinate-to-cartesian-coordinate-relative-to-a/357980#357980)
4. https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/pull/2444/files?file-filters%5B%5D=.cpp

I need to generate a CRS/PROJ in order to do the conversion. I’ve read that this can be done using either a topocentric projection or a concatenation of several projections. Can somebody provide a clear example how this should be done?

Comment: What program are you working with?

Comment: I used the standard export option to download the .osm file. Then used QGIS in order to make a .shp file that can be processed using geopandas.

Comment: I came across the following proj4 projection that does exactly what I need but I can't seem to get it running in pyproj.  any advice?

    enu_proj =  "+proj=pipeline " \
                "+step +proj=cart +ellps=WGS84" \
                "+step +proj=topocentric +ellps=WGS84 +lon_0=5 +lat_0=55 +h_0=200"